# JQuery Scrolling and Some Not So Hidden Headings

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I'm trying to produce a fixed-position header that appears once the user starts scrolling through the page. I'm using JQuery (on a page that also uses Angular) and wanted to fadeIn once the scrollTop is > 250px and disappears immediately (I've been using display: none) the moment it's < 250px.

When scrolling slowly my code works but when scrolling up and down at speed the h1 that should be hidden reappears above the 250px mark: https://jsfiddle.net/gilestaylor/jpaqbm36/

Can anyone recommend a fix? Or else a smarter way of doing this? (I'm still learning the ropes so any tips much appreciated!)

```
HTML
<header>
  <h1>Order some food</h1>
</header>
<div id="bar">
 <h1>Order some food</h1>
</div>

JS
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 250) {
      $('#bar').css({
        'height': '50px'
      });
    $('#bar h1').fadeIn(1000);          
    }
    else {
        $('#bar').css({
            'height': '0'
        });
        $('#bar h1').css({'display': 'none'});
    };
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `fadeIn()` takes time. It may still be animating when you hide the element and even when `.fadeIn()` is called again. Therefore, you should use `.stop()` to stop the animation before doing either of those things. Also, you can use `.hide()` to hide the element, rather than `.css({'display': 'none'})`.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpaqbm36/8/)

To really make the code right though, you should make the change only when needed. That is, you should execute the code to show the bar only when it is not shown, and execute the code to hide it only when it is shown.

```
$(function() {
  var isBarShown = false;

  function updateBar() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 250) {
      if (!isBarShown) {
        $('#bar').css({'height': '50px'}).find('h1').fadeIn(1000);
        isBarShown = true;
      }
    } else {
      if (isBarShown) {
        isBarShown = false;
        $('#bar').css({'height': '0'}).find('h1').stop().hide();
      }
    }
  }

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    updateBar();
  });

  updateBar();
});
```

Note: In this case it is not necessary to call `.stop()` before calling `.fadeIn()` because there will never be two consecutive calls to `.fadeIn()` without an intervening call to `.hide()`.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpaqbm36/11/)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef - Good point, but now that I look at it again, I'm thinking there should be a check so the code does not get executed unless it is switching from above and below the 250 point.

Comment: but without .stop() before fadeIn()  its still show up after animate .. it works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/jpaqbm36/6/

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef - As the windows is scrolled after it is past the 250 point, `.stop().fadeIn()` will get called over and over. It really doesn't do anything since the element is already completely shown, but it seems wrong to keep calling it.

Comment: That's great, thank you for both the code and the walk-through. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having 2 different headers you should have only one header and resize it with jQuery when you scroll down.
check this https://jsfiddle.net/ktriek/jpaqbm36/5/

```
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  var header = $('header');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 250) {
          header.addClass("smaller");           
        }
        else {
              header.removeClass("smaller");    
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. In this case I need two different headers because on the page I'm making the first contains an image but this is a really useful tip for another thing I'm looking to build.